# I am getting an error connecting my label to a database via OLEDB

Tags: connection, database

I have some labels set up in LabelDirect.  They have been working up until now but the database connection details have changed and now I cannot reconnect the label to the database.  The Error I get is

> Login Failed for user 'bcslabels'

However I know it is correct and I have even tried with the sa user and I get the same error

[image]

## Connects Fine

[image]

Then I get an error

[image]

Any Suggestions as to what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I had not ticked the all important

> Allow Saving password

checkbox

[image]

Tick that box and all is right.